# How to parse information from same class using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Suppose I have the following HTML

```
html_doc = """

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class = "Box1">
      <span class = "catagory">Plant</span>
        <div class = "Box2">
          <span class = "sub-catagory">Trees</span>
            <div class = "characters">
              <div class = "font-medium">1.2</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.6</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.7</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.8</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.9</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.4</div>
            </div>
          <span class = "sub-catagory">Flowers</span>
            <div class = "characters">
              <div class = "font-medium">2.2</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">3.6</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">4.7</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">5.8</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">6.9</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">7.4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <span class = "catagory">animals</span>
        <div class = "Box2">
          <span class = "sub-catagory">human</span>
            <div class = "characters">
              <div class = "font-medium">7.2</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">9.6</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">4.7</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">3.8</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">6.9</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">9.4</div>
            </div>
          <span class = "sub-catagory">dog</span>
            <div class = "characters">
              <div class = "font-medium">4.2</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">5.6</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">6.7</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.8</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">3.9</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">8.4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <span class = "catagory">non-living</span>
        <div class = "Box2">
          <span class = "sub-catagory">rock</span>
            <div class = "characters">
              <div class = "font-medium">1.2</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.6</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">4.7</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">6.8</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.9</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">0.4</div>
            </div>
          <span class = "sub-catagory">stars</span>
            <div class = "characters">
              <div class = "font-medium">3.2</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">5.6</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">2.7</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">4.8</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">1.9</div>
              <div class = "font-medium">2.4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

"""
```

Using the BeautifSoup package for Python, I am able to get the category, subcategory, characters separately as shown below:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    catagories = soup.find_all('span',class_='catatory')
    for catatory in categories:
        print(catagory.get_text()) #gives the Plant, Animal, non-living
    sub-catatories = soup.find_all('span',class_='sub-catatory')
    for sub-catatory in sub-categories:
        print(sub-catagory.get_text()) # gives me subcategories
    measurements = soup.find_all('div',class_='font-medium')
    for measurement in measurements:
        print(measurement.get_text()) # gives me all the font-medium together.
```

I am not sure how to get the following result since div classes are all same. Please help

Plant
Trees
1.2
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
1.4
Flowers
2.2
3.6
4.7
5.8
6.9
7.4
animals
human
7.2
9.6
4.7
3.8
6.9
9.4
dog
4.2
5.6
6.7
1.8
3.9
8.4
non-living
rock
1.2
1.6
4.7
6.8
1.9
0.4
stars
3.2
5.6
2.7
4.8
1.9
2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting your texts printed in the expected way, select your `Box1` and extract text with `get_text()` while setting its seperat / join parameter to `\n`:

```
print(soup.select_one('.Box1').get_text('\n',strip=True))

Plant
Trees
1.2
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
1.4
Flowers
2.2
3.6
4.7
5.8
6.9
7.4
animals
...
```

To get a more structured output change the way fetching your elements:

```
for e in soup.select('span.sub-catagory'):
    data.append({
        'cat': e.find_previous('span',{'class':'catagory'}).text,
        'subcat': e.text,
        'characters': list(e.find_next('div').stripped_strings)
    })
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

data = []

for e in soup.select('span.sub-catagory'):
    print()
    data.append({
        'cat': e.find_previous('span',{'class':'catagory'}).text,
        'subcat': e.text,
        'characters': list(e.find_next('div').stripped_strings)
    })
data
```

###### Output

```
[{'cat': 'Plant',
  'subcat': 'Trees',
  'characters': ['1.2', '1.6', '1.7', '1.8', '1.9', '1.4']},
 {'cat': 'Plant',
  'subcat': 'Flowers',
  'characters': ['2.2', '3.6', '4.7', '5.8', '6.9', '7.4']},
 {'cat': 'animals',
  'subcat': 'human',
  'characters': ['7.2', '9.6', '4.7', '3.8', '6.9', '9.4']},
 {'cat': 'animals',
  'subcat': 'dog',
  'characters': ['4.2', '5.6', '6.7', '1.8', '3.9', '8.4']},
 {'cat': 'non-living',
  'subcat': 'rock',
  'characters': ['1.2', '1.6', '4.7', '6.8', '1.9', '0.4']},
 {'cat': 'non-living',
  'subcat': 'stars',
  'characters': ['3.2', '5.6', '2.7', '4.8', '1.9', '2.4']}]
```